# How to execute heavy glute bridges and hip thrusts with resistance bands?

Tags: resistancetraining

I am trying to figure out how can I do heavy glute bridges with resistance bands safely. The reason I use resistance bands is it is portable and fit my current lifestyle. My current glute bridge is 110 kg with barbells(now I don’t have access to the gym). I have done some research on the internet and find different types of resistance band usage on the glute bridge.

[image]

The first one that I found is creating torque on my shoulders. I am worrying about this movement can create injury on my shoulders. Is this movement progressible in the long run?

Comment: Use a bench or something to elevate your body off the ground?

Comment: Thanks but bench is not portable. I need something that I can put it in my suitcase.

Comment: @my-lord I think you can find small stools that fold up and would fit in a suitcase, if you just need something to support your shoulders....

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can anchor the band with your heels. This is the best way I have found:

[Functional Integrated Training-Resistance Band Glute Bridge](https://youtu.be/h3wRW2jBJc0)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, unless you find something strongly anchored to the ground you can't.

Find a pole and use it to do band pull throughs instead, or band deadlifts.

They are not the best substitute for the glute bridge, but they are decent.